# How to create dummies using a long data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I have a data frame with 2 columns and 1316171 rows, but also a data frame with 2 columns and 7621 rows will create the problem.

```
myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}

m <- myFun(7021)
d <- myFun(7021)

df <-data.frame(m,d)
```

I want to create dummy variables, so I am using the following very simple code:

```
genes2 <- fastDummies::dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "m")
```

However, I keep getting this error message:

```
 Warning message:
    In data.table::alloc.col(.data, ncol(.data) + length(unique_vals)) :
      tl (64004) is greater than 10,000 items over-allocated (l = 15170). If you didn't set the datatable.alloccol option to be very large, please report to data.table issue tracker including the result of sessionInfo()
```

I've learned that this happens when you create a data table that is too big to handle and I found on StackOverflow that

By default in v1.8.8 :

> options()$datatable.alloccol
> max(100, 2 * ncol(DT))
> And that it is probably not the best default and there for you should try changing it to:

```
options(datatable.alloccol = quote(max(100L, ncol(DT)+64L))
```

But even after trying that, I get the same error message.

I also learned that you can allocate you should use the `alloc.col` function to pre-allocate required amount of columns in your data.table to a number which will be bigger than expected ncol.

eg:

```
alloc.col(myDataTable, 7021)
```

But unfortunately, this does not work either from my side probably because I am using it before or after the `fastDummies` code.

How can I create the dummy variables and allocate the number of columns in a functional way?

Answer (score 2):

An incomplete answer, but long for a comment.  **tl;dr** you are going to have big-memory problems with your full problem, which can be mitigated by the use of sparse matrices.

- This is a *warning*, not an error: it is worth trying to understand and resolve it, but it shouldn't actually get in the way of doing anything ... ?
- I don't get this warning (I'm using `data.table` version 1.12.8). Does updating your version help?
- I don't see how the code you posted will actually involve `data.table` at all (although it would if you started with `df <- data.table(m,d)` instead of using `data.frame()`)?

You may have a bigger problem if you mean to extend this to 1316171 rows, however.  The example you give creates a 190-Mb object:

```
format(object.size(genes2),"Mb") ## 190.4 Mb
```

We can get to this number by computing `7021 (number of rows) * 7021 (number of columns; see below) * 4 (bytes per integer) / 2^20 (bytes per Mb)`

```
n <- 7021
n*n*4/2^20 ## 188.80434
```

The actual object is a little bit bigger because (1) `fast_dummies` retains the two columns of character vectors `m` and `d` as well; (2) there's a little bit of overhead.

In your example, every row is unique (because the sample space from which you're generating "gene names" is huge), so we end up with as many as dummies (columns) as rows.  If this were true for your full data set (i.e. you had 1316171 *unique* gene names) you would end up with an object that took more than 6 **terabytes** of space.

```
n <- 1316171
n*n*4/2^40   ## 6.3
```

This may be manageable, but probably not with local hardware resources.

Maybe you only have 10,000 distinct gene names? In that case you'll need:

```
m <- 1e4
m*n*4/2^30  ## 49 Gigabytes
```

Handling a 49 Gb object is within reason, but still beyond the scope of most standard hardware (you'll need several multiples of this memory size if you actually want to do anything with this object beyond just storing it in memory).

(I'm using a slightly old-fashioned convention that 1 Kb=2^10 bytes, 1 Mb=2^20, 1 Gb = 2^30, 1 Tb = 2^40).

If the machinery you mean to use downstream will support *sparse matrices*, then I strongly recommend constructing your dummy matrix as a sparse matrix, e.g.:

```
f2 <- Matrix:::fac2sparse(myFun(7021))
dim(f2)  ## 7021 7021
object.size(f2) ## 619400 bytes
```

This is 620 *kilobytes* rather than 188 Mb as before.

The dummy matrix for your full-size problem takes <20 seconds to construct (on a laptop) and 111 Mb to store:

```
system.time(f3 <- Matrix:::fac2sparse(myFun(1316171)))
format(object.size(f3),"Mb")
```